# how pragmatically import and upload feature image to wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

The following code add post in db but not uploading files and not creating thumbnails,

```
$filename=$_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"];
$post_id=1179;
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
$attachment = array(
'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
'post_name' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
'post_content' => '',
'post_parent' => $post_id,
'post_excerpt' => $thumb_credit,
'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

$attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $filename, $post_id);
if($attachment_id != 0) {
wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attach_data);
update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attachment_id);
}
```

its working to post in db but image is not uploading,

Answer (score 0):

```
// Insert the attachment.
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id );

// Make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

// Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```

As per documentation you should have reference to the `image.php` file.

Comment: 'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'], this get extension and type of image and set to db

Comment: try 'post_type' => 'attachment' in the $attachment